# How to differentiate id or class without changing properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a webpage that's using bootstrap-modal.js from [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

bootstrap-modal.js allows you to create "modals." You basically click a button and a little javascript window slides down where you can display different content etc. Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/xt4aQ/44/

I'm going to have several buttons/modals on my webpage, so I have to set it up so each button triggers a different modal.  I assume that the best way to do this is to give them different classes or ids

**Problem,** if I change the ids given by bootstrap-modal.js, it changes the properties of the modals...For example, it may remove or add a black screen backdrop etc. The fiddle linked to above shows how the code below works.

**Question:** Do you know how I could differentiate the modals so that each button triggers a different modal but allow them all to have the same properties?

```
          <div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
              <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn primary">Primary</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn secondary">Secondary</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Button

```
<button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn important">Launch left Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you can't use id's so why not classes? try adding a different class to each modal. Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xt4aQ/52/

And I tried changing the id to number "2" and it works just fine. Just copy all the code and change the id by appending an ascending number.

Comment: well, maybe I don't understand this correctly. In the code in the OP, you see that it has <div id="modal from dom"> and the button also has "modal from dom". When I play around, I see that these are linked. If I change the button to "modalmodal" and the div id to "modalmodal" then they are still linked. However, the class in the button has "btn important" which determines the color and size, while the class in the layout has "modal hide fade" so the class between the button and the layout are not synced the way the "ids" are.... Can you make a suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no linking of classes between the modal and the button. The link exists with the id's. So simply change the name of the ids in both modal and button to create another modal with its own button. The classes are strictly for styling purposes. You can add additional classes if you want to add more styles.

Comment: but if you change the name of the "id" in the modal, it changes the properties of the modal. For example, I changed one modal id to "modalmodal" (from "modal-from-dom") and now when I click it, it produces a black lightbox type screen over the whole page etc.

Comment: Yeah, on your fiddle, there's the black backdrop on both modals, but when I put it on my site (localhost) only one of the modals has the blackbackdrop. changing the id is affecting the properties

Comment: no... you must be doing something else wrong. the id's are how you differentiate different modals... If it is working live but not on your local machine, then something is not connected correctly.